# Select a row and pass id to another element on the page using KendoGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am in ASP.NET MVC environment and I am creating a page with two parts.

1. Grid which shows all the employee data
2. When a user clicks on a particular row in the grid, it shows the employee related data in the part below

I have used the Selectable() attribute on the Grid. However some of the things are not very clear to me that

1. If it raises any event when I do that?
2. If not, how to I read the value of a particular row OR any particular column while doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch event click, you can use

```
 $("body").on("dblclick", "#grid tbody tr", function (e) {
  var grid= $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
  var rowSelect = grid.select();
  var dataSelect = grid.dataItem(rowSelect);
 });
```